# Can't form a Character from a String containing more than one extended grapheme cluster

Tags: swift

While building hangman app i have tried to make one method that will accept clicked letter, put it in a tappedLetter array then checks if its contained in word to find and if it is that letter should be placed at its position in a word we currently trying to make.

The word user wants to find is displayed with "?" instead of its letters so when user click on right letter corresponding "?" is replaced with that letter

The problem appears when I click on a letter app crash. Something is wrong with method and i don't know am i on a right way to solve this with only using one method to replace "?" with letter when its clicked

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var points : UILabel!
    var letterButton = [UIButton]()
    var currentWord : UITextField!
    var wrong : UILabel!
    var score = 0
    var mistake = 0
    var activatedButton = [UIButton]()
  
    var word = ""
    var usedLetter = ""
    var promptWord = ""
    var tappedLetter = [Character]()
```

I'll skip part where i was making NSLayoutConstraint and addSubview

```swift
    @objc func touchedButton(_ sender:UIButton){
        guard let letter = sender.titleLabel?.text else {return}
        
        tappedLetter.append(contentsOf: letter.lowercased())
        print("U clicked on: \(tappedLetter)")
        activatedButton.append(sender)
        sender.isHidden = true
        sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    
        
        if tappedLetter.contains(Character(usedLetter)){ //Error:Thread 1: Fatal error: Can't form a Character from a String containing more than one extended grapheme cluster
            let char = Character(usedLetter)
            for letter in word{
                if letter == char{
                    if let position = word.firstIndex(of: letter){
                        promptWord.remove(at: position)
                        promptWord.insert(letter, at: position)
                    }
                }
            }
                }
    }
    
    func loadlevel(){
      
        if let startWordUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start", withExtension: "txt"){
            if let startWord = try? String(contentsOf: startWordUrl){
                var allWords = startWord.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                word = allWords.randomElement()!
             
                for letter in word {
                    usedLetter.append(Character(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral: letter))
                    promptWord.append("?")
                }
           
                currentWord.text = promptWord
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadlevel()
    }
```

Comment: Change your condition by this : ```if !tappedLetter.filter({usedLetter.contains($0)}).isEmpty {``` from ```if tappedLetter.contains(Character(usedLetter)){ ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast a string of characters as a single character.
I think what you meant to check was is the string usedLetters contains the character in the button.
Try this

```
if usedLetter.contains(Character(letter)) {
```

instead of

```
if tappedLetter.contains(Character(usedLetter)){
```

same thing for

```
let char = Character(/* usedLetter is a full string of characters */)


let char = Character(letter)
```

Comment: It is working now but i have one minor problem with finding index position of letter. If word has two same letters because of using .firstIndex(of:) second letter is not changing - @SeaSpell

Comment: Unfortunately there is no straight forward easy way to answer this question in the comments. You could use a dictionary, key string value array of int to track your letters. You could write a string extension to locate the letters. I suggest posting a new question. What's the best way handle locating all of the positions of a character in a string. Or something like that. In your particular case I would think a simple string extension would be the easiest solution.